# Automatically reload cert and key in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

Right now I'm running a Node backend that serves HTTPS connections. I've setup the server as such:

```
const options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('./../../ssl/keys/{IDENTIFIER}.key').toString(),
cert: fs.readFileSync('./../../ssl/certs/{DOMAIN}_{IDENTIFIER}.crt').toString() 
}; 
https.createServer(options, app).listen(PORT);
```

Where IDENTIFIER is a long string assigned to each keypair. The issue is that every 3 months, my certificates are expiring, causing the server to go down (incoming connections will be flagged by the browser), forcing me to manually edit the identifier to match the newly created certificate and key. Is there any way to automatically update this within Node to limit downtime?

Comment: You could create code that watches a particular directory for a new cert and stops and restarts your server with the new cert.  I'm not aware of any way to hotload a new cert.